# jquery $.ajax() request.fail() not working on 401

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I was trying to use $.getJSON() but wasn't able to handle 401 errors. So I understand I need to use $.ajax()?

I am using:

```
var request = $.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: myVideoURL,
    dataType: "json"
});

request.done(function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
});

request.fail(function(jqXHR,textStatus) {
    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```

(for testing, "app.vzaar.com/api/videos/1152805.json?callback=?" will work. "app.vzaar.com/api/videos/1715426.json?callback=?" will fail with the 401)

Problem is that the console shows the "401 (Unauthorized)" on the GET but the request.fail() never happens.

Comment: a 401 is not a failed request.

Answer (score 1):

You can try capturing the actual event you want, as 401 is not a failure of the ajax request.

```
var request = $.ajax({
  type: "get",
  url: myVideoURL,
  dataType: "json",
  statusCode: {
     401: function() {
       alert( "Auth required" );
   }
 }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift response. I changed to:

    var request = $.ajax({
     type: "get",
     url: myVideoURL,
     dataType: "json",
     statusCode: {
      401: function() {
      alert( "Auth required" );
      }
     }
    });

But the alert does not happen and I get the 401 in the console.

Comment: Are you sure it's returning a 401?  As a quick PoC, it does post the 200 to itself...  http://jsfiddle.net/briansol/K5nJg/1/ (no url param loads itself).  Your url returns no header besides 200.   using:  http://web-sniffer.net/   returns a valid 200 for your demo url above

Comment: console reports: "GET http://app.vzaar.com/api/videos/1715426.json?callback=jQuery1110047983575076796114_1406746186841&_=1406746186842 401 (Unauthorized) jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4"

Comment: realised my jquery was out of date. updated it and request.fail() now fires. thanks for your help, briansol. much appreciated.